# Cannot access member of class in same package

Tags: java, default, visibility, private, jls

Assume I have a base class with a package accessible member:

```
package testcase;

public class B
{
    int b;
}
```

And it has a subclass:

```
package testcase.sub;

import testcase.B;


public class C
    extends B
{   
    int c;
}
```

Now I need to access the member field from within the same package that defined the field:

```
package testcase;

import testcase.sub.C;


public class A
{

    void testcase( C c )
    {
        c.c = 0;             // HINT
        ( (B) c ).b = 1;     // FIRST
        c.b = 2;             // SECOND
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I absolutely understand that `A` cannot access `c.c` and why the line marked HINT does not compile: `C.c` is only visible to code in the same package and while `C.c` is in package `testcase.sub` `A` is in `testcase`.

**However `A` and `B.b` are both in package `testcase` so why does the first assignment compile, while the second does not?**

Comment: Are A, B and C in the same package?

Comment: What makes you think `testcase` is the same package as `testcase.sub`?

Comment: @Raedwald Every class has its package declaration.

Comment: `A` and `B` are both in `testcase`

Comment: I don't agree that this question is a duplicate. I know what the access modifiers mean in general, but this is a very specific question that contradicts what most definitions of the modifiers allow. How can the question be marked as non-duplicate?

Comment: You have to *show in the text of your question* why it is not a duplicate.  You have to convince.

Comment: @Raedwald The question explicitly asks, why the first assignment is allowed while the second is not. I this this clearifies that the concept of public, private, protected and package-protected are known to me. The "duplicated question" is more a "how should these work" instead of a "is there an exception and why" question.

Answer (score 2):

`C` doesn't have access to `B.b`, `B.b` is package level permission and `B` is in the `testcase` package but `C` is in the `testcase.sub` package. Those are not the same package, so `C` has no `b` field.

Comment: The obligatory link to JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1 (see example 6.6-4)

Comment: `B.b` is package level and `A` is in the same package...

Comment: Yes, but `C` does not have access to `B.b` so there is no `b` in `C`. Even though `A` has visibility to `B` that has nothing to do with `C`'s visibility (or in this case lack there of) to `B.b`.

Comment: @Thomas I look at that example multiple times and I still don't think that this matches the problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `C` does not even try to access `B.b`. `A` does. And `A` should have access to `B.b`, which is does, otherwise it would not work after casting...

Comment: @SteffenHeil `A` sees `C` as such and not `B`. Thus if `C` can't access the field in `B` then `A` can't do so either since `c` _is a_ `C` not a `B`.

Comment: @Thomas `A` knows that `C` is a `B`. For example, `A` could call `c.toString()`, so why shouldn't it know that `C` is a `B` ?

Comment: @SteffenHeil even if `A` knows that `C` is a `B` it still treats it as a `C` and knows that it can't see `B.b`.

Comment: @Thomas: I understand that it is the way it is - that I already knew, when the compiler complained. However I still don't understand why and I think this is a **bad** JLS decision (if it is not even a bug in the compiler). `A` knows that `C` is a `B` and it knows that `B` is a `Object` so it can call `c.toString()`. Why shouldn't it be able to access `B.b`. That does not make sense.

Comment: @SteffenHeil well, if you design your code so that `C` is not allowed to access a member of `B` the compiler should comply with that. It should not allow you to access a member of `B` through an instance of `C` because you decided it can't - unless you state you want to treat `c` as a `B` which you are doing by using the cast.

Comment: @Thomas: `C` is not accessing `B.b` in any way and I explicitly denied that. But `C` is no trying to access `B.b`, `A` is.

Comment: @SteffenHeil yes, but `A` knows that `c` is an instance of `C` which doesn't have access to `b` and thus  `A` knows that it also should not be allowed to access `b`. With the cast to `B` you tell `A` that _you_ want `c` to be treated as a `B` so this works then.